# Is it possible in gwt to use an imagemap?

Tags: java, gwt, imagemap

Is it possible in gwt to use a imagemap? I have searched on google but I didn't find something that real helps me.

Answer (score 0):

There isnt' a widget for image maps, but you can write arbitrary html with the [HTML widget](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HTML.html).

Comment: But in this way how can I add a listner to the areas? On click event I have to create a new object and do some operations

Comment: you can use JSNI to call java function from javascript. http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html#methods-fields